# Raspberry Pi Zero HID Emulation not working with one character

Tags: python, hid, raspberry-pi-zero

First of all I want to emphasize that this is my first question in a forum, so I want to apologize for any noob thing....
I'm building a device (using a Raspberry pi zero W) with several functions, but the main one is the hid emulator.

Link to see project images and video: https://anonfiles.com/hcb1Acn9uc/RP0W_rar

[Image with value of each key (Portuguese Layout)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4jr8.jpg)

The following bash script (example) was made with a python script that I made to help building the HID scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
function write_report {
    echo -ne $1 > /dev/hidg0
}
# GUI r
write_report "\x08\0\x15\0\0\0\0\0"

write_report "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

#sleep 0.2 seconds
sleep 0.2

# n
write_report "\0\0\x11\0\0\0\0\0"
# o
write_report "\0\0\x12\0\0\0\0\0"
# t
write_report "\0\0\x17\0\0\0\0\0"
# e
write_report "\0\0\x8\0\0\0\0\0"
# p
write_report "\0\0\x13\0\0\0\0\0"
# a
write_report "\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0"
# d
write_report "\0\0\x7\0\0\0\0\0"

write_report "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

# ENTER
write_report "\0\0\x28\0\0\0\0\0"

write_report "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

#sleep 0.5 seconds
sleep 0.5

# H
write_report "\x20\0\xb\0\0\0\0\0"
# I
write_report "\x20\0\xc\0\0\0\0\0"
# D
write_report "\x20\0\x7\0\0\0\0\0"
#  
write_report "\0\0\x2c\0\0\0\0\0"
# t
write_report "\0\0\x17\0\0\0\0\0"
# e
write_report "\0\0\x8\0\0\0\0\0"
# s
write_report "\0\0\x16\0\0\0\0\0"
# t
write_report "\0\0\x17\0\0\0\0\0"

write_report "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

This bash script was made with a python script that I made to help building the HID scripts.

Everything was working fine until a letter **magically** stopped working.
The letter "g", ("0/0/**xa**/0/0/0/0/0") was no longer working.
I tested it on 2 other computers, both with Windows 10 and still not working, when I tried it on my laptop, which has Linux, it worked, but **what I intend is to work on Windows**.
I've tested several things but still haven't found the error, I even installed it from 0 and configured Raspbian to work with a HID Emulator, but it still didn't work...
I want to point out that **before it was working normally**.
I'm already a few days back from this and I still haven't got it, I hope you can help me find the damn error.

*edit: I installed a virtual machine with windows 7 and it also didn't work. Apparently the error has to do with windows.

*edit: I analyzed the packages using Wireshark (thanks aja) and compared a funcional char ("f") with the "g" (that doesn't work). I noticed that the code for the letter "g" is different from all the others. when pressed, three packages are detected, one of which is to release the key, unlike the other letters, that only two "packages" are detected. The code (hexadecimal 8 bits) comes separate, so 3 bits come first, and then the remaining 5 bits in another "package".

- Look at "**HID Data**":
- [Normal Char Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqOMw.jpg)
- ["G" Char (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXlwO.jpg)
- ["G" Char (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTXg4.jpg)

Comment: I don't see any instances of your problem letter "g" in the code you posted.  And what exactly do you mean by "not working" - does nothing appear for that letter, or does some other character appear?

Comment: the code I posted is just a example. when I write the letter "g" (0/0/xa/0/0/0/0/0), it's just get  ignored, I dont get any error nor other char, it just don't write anything.

Comment: Try releasing each key after it is pressed (as a person would do sitting at a keyboard). I suspect Windows may have corrupted itself somehow by seeing so many keys pressed simultaneously (unlikely, but it's a thought).

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I already tried installing another version of raspbian and configuring it but it didn't work, I don't know what to do anymore... Remenber that I tested in another computers (all windows), plus a windows 7 virtual machine

Comment: I'd capture a Wireshark trace of the USB traffic and check that the missing keystroke is actually making it onto the wire

Comment: I analyzed the packages and compared a funcional char ("f") with the g that doesn't work. I noticed that the code for the letter g is different from all the others. when pressed, three packages are detected, one of which is to release the key, unlike the other letters, that only two "packages" are detected. The code (hexadecimal 8 bits) comes separate, so 3 bits come first, and then the remaining 5 bits. NormalChar: https://pasteboard.co/JUVImJv.jpg CharG(1): https://pasteboard.co/JUVIPSB.jpg CharG(2): https://pasteboard.co/JUVJ27A.jpg